# Getting a "Please Specify a Shipping Method" exception during checkout

Tags: checkout, magento-1, shipping

I've been getting exception logs for this error in production, but I'm unable to reproduce the issue in my local or staging environment, so it's been pretty hard to troubleshoot.

The error originates in `Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote::_validate()` because the `$rate` returned by `$rate  = $address->getShippingRateByCode($method)` is empty.

I've added in some logging to try and get a better idea of what was going on, and I can see that `$method` contains the correct shipping method.

My best guess is that at some point in the process, the shipping rates are being deleted prior to when they should be.

I've noticed that every time this exception occurs, it happens immediately after a legitimate exception, such as an invalid credit card.  I've tried to reproduce the issue by using an invalid credit card, then a valid one, but it doesn't reproduce for me - in staging, production, or local.

My initial hunch was that maybe the shipping method was getting lost somewhere after the first valid exception, but that's not the case, because I see that `$method` has the correct value at the time that this exception is thrown.

The checkout module that I'm using is AwesomeCheckout - it doesn't really to my knowledge have any custom logic when creating orders that should cause problems here, but might be related.

UPDATE: I've added in some code to attempt to recollect the rates if they are missing.

```
protected function _validate()
{
    if (!$this->getQuote()->isVirtual()) {
        $address = $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
        $addressValidation = $address->validate();
        if ($addressValidation !== true) {
            Mage::throwException(
                Mage::helper('sales')->__('Please check shipping address information. %s', implode(' ', $addressValidation))
            );
        }
        $method= $address->getShippingMethod();
        $rate  = $address->getShippingRateByCode($method);

        /**
         * Start Customization
         */
        if (!$this->getQuote()->isVirtual() && !$rate) {
            Mage::logException(new Exception("Rate was empty inside quote validate method, trying to forcefully recalculate"));
            $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
            $this->getQuote()->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false);
            $this->getQuote()->collectTotals();
            $rate  = $address->getShippingRateByCode($method);
        }
        /** End Customization **/             

        if (!$this->getQuote()->isVirtual() && (!$method || !$rate)) {
            Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Please specify a shipping method.'));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using a 3th party shipping extension? Testing with a native Magento method like flatrate would perhaps give some insight whether it's the checkout extension or the shipping extension

Comment: I have also seen a store with this happening in production, often multiple times in succession. We've never been able to reproduce ourselves in any environment.

Comment: @Sander, Yes we're using a 3rd party extension.  I'm pretty sure it's not the root cause though because it returns rates over the collectRates() method just fine and even for the cases where this fails, I can see that rates were returned over the API just fine.

Comment: @Cags, really??!  Good to know, maybe we'll have to tag team this.  It's one of those things that's important but because it reproduces very infrequently, it's not a major priority.

Comment: @SanderMangel, unfortunately trying this out with flatrate isn't an option, because we can't just stop serving up the correct shipping rates to hundreds of customers in production in order to attempt to reproduce the problem.  If I could reproduce this in my local environment, for sure testing against a vanilla shipping method would be one of the first things I'd try.

Comment: Ah yes, if you can't reproduce it in dev it's definitely not an option.

Comment: WHat differs between your dev server and live? (linux distro's?) When I have this type of issue, I make a duplicate of the site, on the live server. Thus copy db, copy entire site folder, and create a new vhost called test.foo.bar This then allows me to reproduce the error on the live server, outside live operations. Be careful of disk space ;) In most cases the issues end up being some php setting/apache module that exists on live, but not in dev.

Comment: Staging and prod are the same, as far as php/nginx configuration goes.  Even if I created an exact clone of production, that likely wouldn't help much, as this problem only occurs <1% of the time randomly with real orders.

Comment: Are you using replication for the database? What caching / session storage is used?

Comment: No, not using database replication.  Using file system for cache and session storage.

Comment: @kalenjordan, I am facing similar issue but was not able to figure out how suppose to resolve this. In live site some time issue arise so i tried to replicate in staging and local but was not able to reproduce the same. Could you please provide me some clue where exactly i need to look into the code. We have subscription system. I've noticed that when I am not setting shipping method it generated "Please specify ..."  but if shipping code would be there than sometime raise an error and working sometime. Any suggestion would be highly appreciate., Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anyone help me : “Please specify a shipping method” @ https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/225297/57334

Comment: Please see https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/76144/magento-1-9-please-specify-a-shipping-method/241424#241424

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to understand how the rates work and how they are requested. Basically rates are requested when `->setCollectShippingRates(true)` is set on shippinAddress object and it result rates to be collected and stored in rates table. This table is emptied afterwards and filled again on new rate request.

what is happening in your case is that error is thrown and request is repeated and rates are not requested but are expected to be there. So try and force the rates collection over

```
getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
```

and then try to recollect totals as well if it does not work

```
getQuote()->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals();
```

be warned that calling collectTotals multiple times can mess up your totals if some extension does not implement totals objects correctly (a common flaw)

Comment: Thanks, makes sense.  Any idea why this would occur so rarely though?  If the payment error was resetting the rates, I'd expect it to happen every time there's a payment error.

Comment: this depends on the flags and if it is called or not if you can replicate this on error then it is easy to trace with debugger. However if your payment method error does not do a full roundtrip to server and just breaks the request with exit it can just break all dependant observer etc execution

Comment: Added in some code and it still failed.  I did forget the `$this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true)` line though so I'm going to try that now.

Comment: The issue re-occurred, and the code I have in place did prevent the exception from occurring.  But the transaction still failed because SIMULTANEOUSLY braintree was down for a few minutes.  Unbelievable.

Comment: Still hasn't occurred again.  Looking back at my logs, the longest period of time that it went *without* happening was 7 days going back to August.  It's been 9 days since it last occurred.

Comment: so i don't understand did it happen again or not ?

Comment: The problem doesn't appear to have occurred again, in order to give the fix a chance to prove itself.  It should log an exception when the issue occurs, but the order should still go through.  That hasn't happened yet.

Comment: @kalenjordan I am having the exact same issue on a site. Can you clarify where you had placed the code that fixed it?

Comment: Crazy -- in `Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote` - just dropped it in as a core hack temporarily to validate the logic.  Once I validated it, I was planning to refactor it into a proper rewrite or observer.

Comment: Finally occurred again.  36 days later.  The fix didn't help!! :/  @ProxiBlue, have you figured anything out?

Comment: Okay scratch that.  The reason it occurred this time was for entirely different reasons.  A subscription order was trying to be generated for an address where there actually were no shipping rates available, so the error message was valid.  @ProxiBlue

Comment: add it as answer then

Comment: @kalenjordan I am tentatively waiting to see if it happens. I implemented in an observer/event, as changing core files would not get my code past peer-review. I will post my observer code once I am happy it has solved the issue/not caused more issues

Comment: @kalenjordan My observer event had not worked :( Still have quite a few of them. I have now implemented a rewrite of the 'Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote' model, with code as yours. Waiting to see if this works.

Comment: I'd love to connect by email since we're both trying to tackle this same issue.  kalen at cleanprogram

Comment: @kelenjordan: I think I have solved this issue on my site. In the end the issue was usage of custom checkout called CheckItOut (by ecomdev) - it fires a alot of ajax calls to populate data (for example when shipping was selected) During those calls the Submit Payment' button is supposed to be disabled, and only enable when all ajax calls complete. This was not happening, and was always enabled. Customers thus clicked to complete payment, but not all data from the ajax has completed. This seemed to be happening for clients with slower internet, thus ajax took longer to complete.

Comment: Okay the issue has reoccurred a couple of times now, outside of the subscription order case which was unrelated, and the fix appears to have worked!

Comment: Today we alos saw this issue. If it is  real issue - and seeing it is by all these responsesL maybe consider dropping in a FIX here: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts -- thx

Comment: @AntonS could you pls help me : https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/225297/57334

Answer (score 3):

Might have figured this out.  I had a related exception that was being thrown with about the same frequency as this one, which was "The requested Payment Method is not available".

Turns out that the reason it was happening was because one of my observers off of `sales_place_order_after` was creating a quote object (and saving it) in order to generate some subscription pricing.

I was able to get it to reproduce by first checking out with a bad credit card as a new customer (not logged in), then going back and fixing the credit card and attempting to checkout again.

The exception was throwing because in the `loadCustomerQuote` observer of `customer_login`, it will merge your quotes together if you have more than one quote, and in so doing it loses some of the payment method information on the quote.

The fix was to delete the new quote that I was creating in my subscription observer.

UPDATE: Nope, the fix for "The requested Payment Method is not available" didn't resolve this issue, still occurring.

Comment: Quite late, but this is why I don't use that event (sales order place after) at all anymore. If I need something to happen after an order I fetch into a queue.

Comment: Like same will you help me to solve “Please specify a shipping method” in checkout page error: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/225297/57334

Answer (score 0):

Just noting, sometimes PayPal Express will give an error saying "Payer not identified" upon order placement. This error stems from the same "Please specify a shipping method" exception. In Magento 1.8.1.0 this is easily reproducible by causing a "quote merge" or "cart merge" upon order placement. Merging quotes or carts will cause the shipping rates to be cleared but not recalculated. And actually, you don't want to fix this, because then the customer might be paying more than what they agreed on! Instead you'll want to remove the merging functionality - or upgrade Magento.

This is fixed in 1.9; customers first have to log in before they get redirected to PayPal .

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error its originate from `null` value in `$method` and `$rate`

```
$method= $address->getShippingMethod();
$rate  = $address->getShippingRateByCode($method);
    if (!$this->getQuote()->isVirtual() && (!$method || !$rate)) {
Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Please specify a 
shipping method.'));
}
```

so i set a rate from this. in method and rate that available in your magento

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$address = $quote->getShippingAddress();
$shippingMethod = 'amtable_amtable5';
$shippingMethod = 'flatrate_flatrate';
$address->setCollectShippingRates(true)->collectShippingRates()->setShippingMethod($shippingMethod);
```